# How embed gps and other data in a webcam stream to be used in a web page?

Tags: video, gps, video-streaming

I have a server that is connected to a webcam and a GPS (its position can change). I need to dump the video stream in files together with the GPS coordinates and the recording time.
Then I need to show these video files in a web page along with the coordinates and the right recording time. So I need to extract these information in a browser.

What approach should be used to add these information to the video files?